# How to fix A0 error code of a Daikin split system air conditioner

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel

When I tried to turn on my split system AC today, the indicator light just kept blinking and the air conditioning was not on.

Here is the error code as displayed on the remote

[image: error code a0]

According to what I found on Daikin, the **Error conditions decision** is `When an open circuit occurs between external input terminals with the remote controller set to
"external ON/OFF terminal"`.

I have no idea what it means.

I suspect it is related to some recent severe storms in my local area (Sydney, Australia).

I tried to switch the circuit breakers on and off but it has no effect (Blue ones in the following picture)

[image]

Would it help if I toggle the main isolator? I do not know how to toggle the switch though.

The model no of the unit is: FTXS35GVMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, I need to turn off the blue switches above (the circuit breaker) for at least 3 minute and then turn it back on. The indoor unit resets itself after this and is functioning again.